# Error installing Eclipse plugin from repository

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install a plugin from a repository in eclipse but when I do it this error appears:

> An error occurred while installing the items
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null -->
>   [R]com.googlecode.veloeclipse.ui 2.0.8, action=).
>   Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.googlecode.veloeclipse.ui 2.0.8.

I've read that by deleting the artifacts.xml file in the Eclipse root folder it solve the problem, but it doesn't.

How can we resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the porblem I've just added a previous plugin:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4
Eclipse Test, Examples and Extras -> Eclipse 2.0 Style PLugin Support

and then I've installed Veloeclipse.

Hope it helps.